# How to Get Column Name From Entity Type Configuration With Property Name In EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have such EntityTypeConfiguration class.

```
public class DummyTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DummyType>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DummyType> builder)
  {
      builder.HasNoKey();
      builder.Property(p => p.SecretId).HasColumnName("secretID");
      ...
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the column name: "secretID" by using the property DummyType.SecretId as such:

```
var columnName = ...(DummyType.SecretId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EF Core 6:** That can be done using the code below:

```
var entityType = _dataContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(DummyType));
var property = entityType?.GetProperty(nameof(DummyType.SecretId));
var columnName = property?.GetColumnName();
```

The `_dataContext` variable represents object instance of `DbContext` class.

Answer (score 0):

When using [TPH for storing entities class hierararchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration), there can be case when some derived entities have the same property name. Column names in the database table then needs to be different for the two entities.

For example:

BaseClass class

- DerivedClassA

  - string Name
- DerivedClassB

  - string Name

Table BaseClass

- column Name
- column DerivedClassB_Name

This behavior is mentioned here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11046

GetColumnName() method returns "Name" for both cases.
To get the real column name, method GetColumnName must be called with parameter StoreObjectIdentifier.Table(tableName).
This returns "Name" for DerivedClassA entity and "DerivedClassB_Name" for DerivedClassB entity.

So, te code would be:

```
var entityType = _dataContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(DummyType));
string tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
var property = entityType?.GetProperty(nameof(DummyType.SecretId));
var columnName = property?.GetColumnName(StoreObjectIdentifier.Table(tableName));
```